# Django won't serve static files while using development server

Tags: css, django, django-templates, django-views

I just started a new development server for a website I am working on and I can't seem to get the Django development server to serve the static files I have for CSS and other things. The CSS for the admin site loads fine. I am running it in a virtualenv sandbox.

In settings.py I've messed around with MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL.

So far for MEDIA_ROOT I've tried.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/wluw/wluw/wluw/media'
```

and

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media')
```

I changed my ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX to

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/admin_media/'
```

my MEDIA_URL looks like this

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and the urls.py section for the static files looks like this.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns('',
     (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',         
     {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

Here's the output from the dev server when I try to access the page.

```
[21/Jul/2011 21:19:25] "GET /media/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[21/Jul/2011 21:19:25] "GET /media/css/style.css/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2561



from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, handler500, handler404
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
import d51_django_admin_piston

handler500 = 'radio.frontend.views.server_error'

admin.autodiscover()
d51_django_admin_piston.autodiscover(admin.site)

urlpatterns = patterns(
'',
(r'^logs/', include('radio.logs.urls')),
(r'^events/', include('radio.events.urls')),
(r'^station/', include('radio.station.urls')),
(r'^staff/', include('radio.staff.urls')),
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
(r'^', include('radio.frontend.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns('',
     (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',         
    # {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True})
)
```

Here is my radio.frontend.urls

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *


urlpatterns = patterns('radio.frontend.views',
    url(r'^$', 'home', name='home'),
)
```

Here is my settings.py
[settings.py](http://pastebin.com/JTWAJFCz)

Everything was working fine on the production server having /media? being the url for css and other things.

Also none of the content in the database is being shown. Each page of the site is created with a base.html and a viewname.html. Only the base.html part is showing up. I am sure this is a topic for an other question though.

I've looked at a ton of other posts with people having the same problem and none of them provided a solution. I am completely stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Tryputting a `/` at the end of your `MEDIA_ROOT` as thats what i have but i can't remember if it was important or not. Its been a while since i've had to set up a new project.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: add `{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}` and see if you can navigate to the directory. Are you getting 404 errors?

Comment: It looks like it is thinking that style.css is a directory.

Comment: Why is it looking for `/static/` and not `/media/` ? thats what I would be asking.

Comment: Whoops. I was messing around with some things. I've gotta switch back to my old config. It's back to media now. With the same settings as I posted above

Comment: still with the trailing slash? Whats the 404 page say if you try to navigate to `/media/css/style.css` ?

Comment: The 404 page just displays the home page with no content and no style. It's not really a 404 page though.

Comment: When I navigate to the style.css home page i8 shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access your static files via '/static/' instead of '/media/' since in your comments you say:

```
"GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 302 0 [21/Jul/2011 21:13:31] "GET /static/css/style.css/ HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Either you access it that way:

```
"GET /media/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 302 0 [21/Jul/2011 21:13:31] "GET /media/css/style.css/ HTTP/1.1" 404
```

And you set you URL in your templates accordingly.

Or, you setup your routing this way:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns('',
     (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',         
    # {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True})
)
```

I'll choose the second one and would setup `settings.STATIC_FILE` as you usually use `MEDIA_ROOT` for upload/download content.

Comment: The static part was a screw up when I was fooling around with different settings. It now reads 


GET /media/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 302 0 [21/Jul/2011 21:13:31] "GET /media/css/style.css/ HTTP/1.1" 404

Answer (score 4):

In Django 1.3 `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` are used to configure the physical location for user-uploads.

For static files you should use **STATIC_URL**:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' # URL prefix for static files.
```

and **STATICFILES_DIRS**:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

also make sure that you have `STATICFILES_FINDERS` configured.

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

In your templates you can use the STATIC_URL variable to access the location of your static files:

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

That should be enough for the development env./server. No need to configure anything in urls.py.

For more information you can visit official django doc site describing how to manage static files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: The thing is on the poduction server MEDIA_ROOT works just fine. I don't want to have to go through all of my templates and change static to media. Plus there is a bunch of images that need to be used by MEDIA_ROOT.

Comment: Do you think I should go through all my code and change mEDIA TO STATIC

Comment: @thebeagle maybe your static url and media root can be the same?

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be in your `urls.py`, since the AppendSlashMiddleware - which is what is causing the redirect to the URL ending in a slash - only kicks in if the URL is not matched at all, and from what you've shown it should match.

Silly question, but are you sure `DEBUG` is True? Can you show the rest of the urls.py? Are you sure that's the main urls.py, not one that's included by another?

**Edit** OK, it's hard to tell without seeing your `radio.frontend.urls` file, but it looks like what's happening is that all the URLs are being matched against that - because you use `r'^'` to include it, which matches everything, aomething in that file is also being too general. You might want to break up the first urlpattern, and put the include *after* the static bit.

Comment: I added the urls.conf to the main post

Comment: The DEBUG is set to true. I'm going to post a link to my settings.py.

Comment: I'll post my radio.frontend.urls up in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

For the development server

1. Make a static folder in the django root
2. Add this to the STATIC_DIRS in settings.py ('assets','path to the static folder')
3. Put the Resources in the respective folders in the static folder you had created earlier
4. Then run python manage.py collectstatic. This will create an admin and an assets folder in    the django root with the assets you have put
5. In the Templates add {% load static %} at the top
6. For the link use {% static 'assets/path_to_resources_as_added_in_the_static_folder' %}

This works for me