# Django dev server STILL won't serve static files

Tags: django, django-dev-server

Okay, all. I know this is a question that many people have solved in various cases, but I cannot for the life of me get my Django 1.9 development server to serve static content on my local computer. Static files worked fine pre-deployment, and are totally fine on my deployment server, but now in my test environment (local computer with `runserver` going) everything is broken, and I *really* need to be able to test stylesheets in a dev environment.

I have tried [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594145/django-not-serving-static-files) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398600/django-runserver-not-serving-static-files-in-development) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026010/trying-to-serve-django-static-files-on-development-server-not-found) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784034/django-wont-serve-static-files-while-using-development-server) and more, followed the documentation guide, used `collectstatic` again in the development repo... nothing has worked, and I am at my wits' end.

Currently, I have `DEBUG = True`, and the following setup:

**Folder Hierarchy**

```
project/
   manage.py
   (&c)
   app/
     urls.py
     models.py
     (&c)
   project/
     settings.py
     urls.py
     (&c)
   static/
     styles/
     images/
     (&c)
```

**settings.py Static Files Settings**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'styles/'),
    os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'js/'),
    os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'audio/'),
    os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'images/'),
    os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'admin/'),
    os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'documents/'),
)
```

**urls.py URL Patterns**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    # ... project url patterns blah blah ...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}))
```

I also have `{% load staticfiles %}` in my templates along with the appropriate `{% static %}` calls (ex: `{% static 'styles/main.css' %}`).

For reference, the command line gives me the following when I load the page:

`"GET /static/styles/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1759`

If anyone knows of a fix I have missed that might even remotely have a snowball's chance of working, *please* let me know. It's driving me bonkers not being able to test properly.

**EDIT: As suggested, I have updated to Django 1.11 on my local machine, with no changes to the current issue.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test it out, but maybe try changing this:

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

to this:

`STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')`

By the way, version 1.9 is unsupported and also a security risk. You'd probably want to upgrade to another version.

Comment: No dice. As far as I know, `os.path.join()` appends & inserts the necessary slashes (which is why it's preferred over simple string concatenation). Upgrading is my next priority.

Comment: Darn. Sorry about that. 

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to create the STATIC_ROOT var with the absolute path and check if it works?

Maybe the construction of that var is not OK.

You could also check the STATIC_ROOT var through

```
python manage.py shell
```

and see if it correctly fits your path.

Comment: According to the shell, STATIC_ROOT points to the right path (project/static/).

Comment: @JensenReynolds is that an absolute path?  From your comment I can't see if it is.

Comment: @JensenReynolds Does it show the same behavior with `DEBUG = False`?

Comment: It does, although the numbers on the GET 404 messages are different. Instead of 1759, it's now 96. I don't know if that's even relevant.

Comment: Did you include `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`? By the way, the number you obtain from the `runserver` is the number of bytes served by each call.

Comment: Yes, `django.contrib.staticfiles` is there.